# How to redirect to route using custom attribute routing in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I'm not sure if what I'm attempting to do is valid as I'm a relative newbie to the C# / ASP.NET / MVC stack.

I have a controller action like this in **ModelController.cs**

```
//Get
[Route("{vehiclemake}/models", Name = "NiceUrlForVehicleMakeLookup")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string vehicleMake)
{
    // Code removed for readaility

    models = await db.VehicleModels.Where(make => make.VehicleMake.Make == vehicleMake).ToListAsync();

    return View(models);
}
```

and in another controller called **VehicleMakeController.cs**, I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("VehicleMake/AddNiceName/{makeId}")]
public ActionResult AddNiceName(VehicleMake vehicleMake, int? makeId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var vehicle = db.VehicleMakes.Find(makeId);
        vehicle.MakeNiceName = vehicleMake.MakeNiceName;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToRoute("NiceUrlForVehicleMakeLookup");
    }
    VehicleMake make = vehicleMake;
    return View(make);
}
```

What I would like to do, is in where I'm returning when a db update is successful, redirect to the custom route I defined ( this part:  *return RedirectToRoute("NiceUrlForVehicleMakeLookup");* )

The views I'm using are just standard views, can this be accomplished or do I need to start looking into Partials or Areas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No need to use areas or partial views.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specifying a route name doesn't automatically mean that the route values are supplied. You still need to supply them manually in order to make the route match the request.

In this case, your route requires a `vehicleMake` argument. I am not sure exactly how you would convert your `vehicleMake` type to a string that can be used with your route, so I am just showing `ToString` in this example.

```
return RedirectToRoute("NiceUrlForVehicleMakeLookup", new { vehicleMake = vehicleMake.ToString() });
```

Comment: Thanks @NightOwl888, that was almost exactly perfect, I ended up with this `return RedirectToRoute("NiceUrlForVehicleMakeLookup", new {vehicleMake = vehicleMake.Make});` and that solved my issue. I would upvote your answer but don't have enough rep yet :)